# Word for first sale of the day

Tags: single-word-requests

In the Indian subcontinent, the first sale of the day by a shopkeeper is considered very auspicious. I am sure it would be the same in other countries as well. Is there a single word or phrase for it?

The users with Hindi as their native tongue would understand that I am talking about *bohani*.

Comment: One option is to adopt "bohani" as a loan word.

Comment: Suggested edit: ... analogous to *first-foot* of Scotland/ Northern England usage, only that here it relates to daily business.

Comment: Certain words owe their existence to cultural and ethnic beliefs and practices. Equivalent terms do not exist in other linguistic denominations unless identical practices also exist.

Comment: @slim: 'loan word' for what? It can be used only in the context where it is relevant, and there it already exists in the native tongue, doesn't it?

Comment: @kris a loan word is a word taken from a foreign language. e.g. the French borrow "le picnic"; Japanese drink from a "kappu" (cup). English borrows "entrepreneur" from French. So an English speaker might say "I was excited about today's bohani - someone was waiting at the door when I opened up, and immediately bought an iPad". We already borrow lots of words from Sanskrit. "Avatar", "mantra", "nirvana"...

Comment: @slim: The Japanese would not have loaned a word if they had no cups in the first place, right?

Comment: @Kris more likely the other way around; but although it's more common to use a loan-word when the native language has no equivalent, it's not unusual for loan words to become popular even though there's a native equivalent, just because the loan word is catchier somehow. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loan_word

Comment: 'I am sure it would be the same in other countries as well.'.. This is quite a big assumption. It's like saying 'I am sure shaking of the head is a gesture of denying/declining in other countries as well.', when most of us here know this is not the case. I am not aware of such a term in English. This is a lacuna that can only be filled by borrowing from another language if the situation ever arises to express such a notion.

Comment: Sounds like "breaking the day's sales-duck" to me! Surely a metaphor that would work in cricket-loving India. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Handsel** or **hansel** can be used.

> Handsel (n.):
>
> 1. The first act of using any thing; the first sale.
> 2. An earnest; money for the first sale. [Little used.]
>
> Hansel (n.):
>
> A gift or bribe, the first money received in a day. Hence Hansel
>   Monday, the first Monday of the year.

*Hansel* is also used as a variant of *handsel*.

Comment: In Turkish, we call it _siftah_.

Comment: +1. Confirmed by the OED as being 'the first money taken by a trader in the morning'.

Comment: Better to just use the original in italics and explain it at the first use. I would find it disruptive to come upon this word in the flow of a narrative about some culture that places value in the first sale of the day. I would expect to see the word used within that culture, italicized.

Comment: You, sir, are awesome.

Comment: Which dictionary is this? It doesn't concur with any of the online dictionaries I've consulted. Closest is thefreedictionary.com with "*The first money or barter taken in, as by a new business or on the opening day of business, especially when considered a token of good luck.*" -- different enough that you couldn't use it as a direct replacement. Some dictionaries have nothing close to this definition.

Comment: Any relation of 'Hansel' of *Hansel and Gretel*?

Comment: I agree with sq33G, use it with care. One of its many meanings may match *bohani* but I've never heard of it before. Definition 2 above also says "[Little used.]", and  other dictionaries also define it as the very first sale of the very first day, not just for any given day. Or it can be a gift for the start of the year or at the start of an enterprise.

Comment: @Kris: 'Hansel', the Bavarian/Austrian name, is a diminutive of Hans, which is itself a diminutive of 'Johan/Johannes'. Here the etymology is 'hand - sale'.

Comment: The entry for _handsel_ in Webster's 1828 Dictionary: http://www.1828-dictionary.com/d/word/handsel

Comment: 'money for the first sale. [Little used.]': As of 1828, the word was rarely used in this sense. And, perhaps, the sentiment, and therefore the particular implication of the word, faded into oblivion?

Answer (score 10):

From my experience in UK retail, and my general knowledge of British and American culture, I know there is no such special significance given to the first sale of the day in most modern Western culture. There is certainly not a widely understood word dedicated to it.

Comment: @JasperLoy the question is "Is there a single word or phrase for it?" and the answer is "no". If someone proves me wrong, I'll delete this answer. We get lots of questions of the form ("Is there a single English word for [something that has a word in their language but doesn't in English]. There needs to be a "no there is not" answer that can be upvoted and accepted, if it's the truth.

Comment: Whenever I see "I believe" or "I think that..." in an answer, I am inclined to think it should be a comment too.

Comment: As @Mehper shows, the answer *isn't* no.

Comment: I briefly deleted this post, but have reinstated it after a survey of four online dictionaries didn't agree that *handsel* means this. I am updating, though, to say "commonly understood". Presumably OP wants to be understood!

Comment: @tenfour - I, like many other people, often use 'uncertain'  phrases like 'I believe' in this kind of context. If slim thought there was an answer he would be definitive - `Yes, the answer is...`. But it's more difficult to assert with confidence that something doesn't exist - so you might mitigate the answer with `[To the best of my knowledge] I believe...`. Slim's answer was not a 'comment', nor was it a casual guess - it was his answer; one that he is reasonably confident in, but nevertheless, he is accepting that he might be proved wrong.

Comment: So we only allow *correct* answers, @onomatomaniak? The fact that there exists such a word does not change the fact that "no such word" is a valid, though possibly incorrect, answer.

Comment: If you had not commented, wouldn't the philosophical argument still have existed?

Comment: @JeffSahol I'm not in the business of allowing/denying anyone's answers, nor am I able to say all of my own answers are correct. I do think, though, that giving *I've never heard of X, so X doesn't exist* as an authoritative answer is less than useful. The edited version of this answer is much more reasonable (though I'd more likely post it as a comment, in any case).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @onomatomaniak. It's easy to lose the sense of what someone is trying to say without reviewing the whole thread sometimes, and I apologize for judging your statement based on face value.

Comment: @onomatomaniak, The answer is still effectively no, despite Mehper's answer.  Very few English native speakers, myself included, have ever heard the word "Handsel" and they would not understand its meaning if they did.

Answer (score 1):

How's *first-foot*?

In Scotland and the North of England, the [first-foot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-foot) is the first person to enter your house in the New Year.  If you choose the right person and perform the proper ceremonies, the first-foot can bring luck to your house for the rest of the year.

Comment: Clutching at straws. This isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: I'm not suggesting they are the same.  What I am suggesting is that they have some similarity, and if I were to use the word "first-foot" in the context of Indian shop-keeping customs, you would know exactly what I meant.

Comment: I might guess what you meant; that you were drawing a metaphor between first-footing and the first sale. But he didn't ask for a metaphor. Also I would assume you meant the first person through the shop's door, not the first sale. Not everyone buys.

Comment: I take your point that the first person doesn't always buy.